# How to retrieve a specific object through a relationship in core data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

Say I have 2 managed objects in my model: `Department` and `Employee` (as discussed in the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001803-SW3)).  If I already have a specific department retrieved, I know I can get all employees in that department through

```
NSSet *departmentsEmployees = aDepartment.employees;
```

but what if I want to find a specific employee (e.g. with employeeId = 123) in that set, change one of its attributes, then save the change?  How do I do that?  Can I do a targeted query on the set?  Or would I have to loop through each employee to find the one I want?

It seems that it would be better to try to find it in the `employees` NSSet instead of doing a whole new query to the entire data model because I already have a specific department.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to narrow the search is to use `-[NSSet filteredSetUsingPredicate:]`.